# Mercurial equivalent of git reset --hard rev so that incoming works

Tags: mercurial

I'm working on a golang dependency manager, and I need help with one aspect of Mercurial. I want to grab a remote repository, then reset it to a particular revision. I can do this using `hg update -r rev`, and that works. But the problem with that is that it doesn't reset the local repository so that `hg incoming` works as I'd expect it to, which is to show me all commits between the now current revision on my local repository and the tip of the remote repository. I can do this with git, using `git reset --hard rev`. Anything similar in Mercurial?

Comment: 'git reset --hard rev' is not equivalent to 'hg incoming'. What do you use in git to show what you want? 'git reset' is not all of the story here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you talk about grabbing the remote repository, I assume you're cloning it. In that case, you should probably simply clone up to the revision you want:

```
$ hg clone http://server/repo -r revision_you_want
```

That will simply clone all revisions up to the specified revision and `hg incoming` will then show you the later revisions.

If you don't know the revision you want before you've cloned the repository, then you can use `hg strip` to delete the extra revisions.